# Magento 2: Creating Data Objects with Immutable State?

Tags: layout, magento2, design-patterns

Dovetailing off [a comment in another Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82373/magento-2-passing-variables-from-controller-action-to-view)

> If you need to share some calculated value, put the calculation behavior to separate object and call it from blocks that require that value. Registry is discouraged because it's global mutable state and you are never sure what you will get from there.

Is there a way to create an Object in Magento 2 with immutable state?  Using the registry (`Magento\Framework\Registry`) is discouraged because *it's global mutable state* (presumable because, although the `register` method doesn't let you change an existing key, you **can** unset and then reset that key).

However -- the same problem exists for any object in Magento 2.   If I were to create an object

```
namespace Pulsestorm\Helloworld\Model;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class ViewVars extends DataObject
{
}
```

Then automatic constructor dependency injection ensures that anyone could grab that shared object.  If the object is unshared, then the view/block can't grab it.

In theory, we could do something like

```
namespace Pulsestorm\Helloworld\Model;

class ViewVars
{
    protected $_data=false;
    protected function setData($data)
    {
        if($_data)
        {
            throw new Exception("Immutable");
        }
        $this->_data = $data;
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->_data;
    }
}
```

But *that seems like a lot of work for a task as common as setting individual variables for a view*.  Is there a better way in Magento 2 to create immutable data objects I'm not aware of?

Comment: Doesn't the old Mage Registry pattern attempt to make the value immutable? IMHO this should be a lang construct. M2 is compatible with HHVM so if you desperately needed this construct you could adopt Hack, which provides immutable data types. Obviously this is said in both jest and with my head cocked to the side as if to gesture that this may actually be a Thing One Could Do™.

Comment: I think the point of Anton's comment was more that if you're using a registry interface, there is no guarantee about what you're actually getting out. You can say, 'okay, I'm going to store \My\Model in registry key current_model here, and use that as needed'. But (1) nothing guarantees that current_model is an instance of \My\Model (or anything at all); and (2) any code anywhere else in the execution path could use or modify that registry key in any way. That could cause big problems. Better to use a defined interface and singleton with dependency injection to maintain that state data.

Comment: Object with setters is not  immutable. Use constructor to set data in object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, currently is no better way in Magento 2 to create immutable data objects.
You may create it, for example by generation getters and constructor from interface.