# Magento 2: How to get data from controller to block/view

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers, dataflow, best-practice

I am looking for the right flow of data of how Magento wants me to do it. I have some data which I want to pass to the view. How do I do this the right way?

I saw the following answer for Magento 1.x https://stackoverflow.com/a/4006908/2190322

Does this apply in the same way for Magento 2? Are there differences in the flow/implementation or is it the same? If there are some differences which are these and how do I implement them?

I also saw this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/82376/5827 But it has no answer regarding to best practices, which I am looking for.

Comment: Here you have a good and simple explanation of how to do it: https://magemastery.net/courses/magento-2-beginner/passing-data-from-controller-to-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not passing data from Controller Action to View. Use block to for passing data to View (template engine).

Comment: I am not asking to pass data from controller to a view. I chose my formulation with care. I am asking how to "get" data from a controller to a block/view. Actually you gave the same answer to the question of the second link, so I knew this allready. I am looking for a more extensive answer how to acomplish this. Maybee you can edit your answer and explain how to do it instead of what to do. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand what it means to "get." Do you want to receive the data in block  from the controller? Or  Do you want to the controller set data in block?

Comment: What I want is show the contents of a variabele which I have in the controller on thee screen of a user :) I am looking for the right flow reagarding magento conventions.

Comment: Can you move code that get data form controller to block?

Comment: I don't know. I don't think so. The data is comming from \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter::(SELECTED|EXCLUDED)_PARAM. It holds the order id's from the selected orders from the sales grid. It is avaiable in the massAction action in the controller at the moment.

Comment: You can use \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter in you block, i do not see reason to not do it

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. Thanks again :)

Comment: I instantiated the Filter object in the block as you suggested and it works great. Maybee your answer in this case could be more comprehensive by telling data should´t be passed from controller to block, but to get the data right in the block class in the first place. My problem is fixed so i'll accept it. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 14):

One approach is to use the registry so in your controller class you put it in the registry, and then in your block you can retrieve it.

```
<?php

namespace <Vendor>\<ModuleName>\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('foo', 'bar');
        return $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Then in your block you can do;

```
<?php

namespace <Vendor>\<ModuleName>\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Moo extends Template
{
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getFoo()
    {
        // will return 'bar'
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('foo');
    }
}
```

Obviously you need to get your block on the page in the first place but this should give you a good start.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the best practice and/or convention?

Comment: If you take the time to look through the Magento code you will see they use this technique to store the current category and current product so it can be accessed later on.

Comment: it's magento 1 practice, in m2 try to avoid it.

Comment: What is your solution @KAndy ?

Comment: @Smartie, Gets data direct in block

Comment: @KAndy I understand that but the data needs to exist somewhere for you to be able to get it in the first place.

Comment: you can introduce some  specific class for this for example ProductLocator with method get that return data

Comment: I am getting error "Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Allin\ReorderForm\Controller\Index\Search::__construct()"

Comment: How can we achieve the same for admin custom module?

Comment: for some one who get error " Argument 1 passed to .. something" , you need to delete gerenate folder and clear cache, and every thing will be work, it solved my problems a lot of time. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: In <Vendor>\<ModuleName>\Block\Moo 

use  \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context instead   \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context in constructor

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way:

In your controller:

```
//\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
// your.block.name is from your layout
$block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('your.block.name');
$block->setData('my_key', $data);
```

and now in template:

```
$data = $block->getData("my_key");
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: My first try, but for some reason it is null there :thinking:

Comment: Make sure your block is correct `your.block.name`. This should match with what you have in your layout.

Comment: Already checked and its right, the block returned is the one expected; but even so on its $data the key isn't there