# How to return search API response from controller in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, api, controllers, search, response

I have an API(ukvehicledata) for search using registration id.

I want to integrate with magento 2.2

I am getting response in controller as JSON format. I have converted it into an array.

Now I want to return the response to the search result page.

I am using below code:

```
<?php 
public function execute()
    {
        $this->layerResolver->create(Resolver::CATALOG_LAYER_SEARCH);

        /* @var $query \Magento\Search\Model\Query */
        $query = $this->_queryFactory->get();

        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $query->setStoreId($storeId);

        $queryText = $query->getQueryText();

        if ($queryText != '') {

        // Init cURL session
        $curl = curl_init();

        // Set API Key
        $ApiKey = "675D83AAC4C8-E9C9-E9C9-E9C9-675D83AAC4C8";


        // Construct URL String
        $url = "https://uk1.domainname.co.uk/api/datapackage/%s?v=2&api_nullitems=1&key_vrm=%s&auth_apikey=%s";
        $url = sprintf($url, "VehicleData", $queryText, $ApiKey); // Syntax: sprintf($url, "PackageName", "VRM", ApiKey);
        // Note your package name here. There are 5 standard packagenames. Please see your control panel > weblookup or contact your account manager

        // Create array of options for the cURL session
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => $url,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
        ));

        // Execute cURL session and store the response in $response
        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        // If the operation failed, store the error message in $error
        $error = curl_error($curl);

        // Close cURL session
        curl_close($curl);

        // If there was an error, print it to screen. Otherwise, unserialize response and print to screen.
        if ($error) {
          echo "cURL Error: " . $error;
        } else {
          //$respons = json_decode($response, true); // For demonstration purposes - Unserialize response & dump array contents to screen
          $results = json_decode($response, true);
          $responsee = $results->Response->DataItems->VehicleRegistration;
          /*echo '<ul>';
          foreach ($responsee as $key => $value) {
              echo '<li>'.$key.' => '.$value.'</li><br/>';
          }
          echo '</ul>';*/

        } else {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use search Criteria

Answer (score 0):

> I have an API(ukvehicledata) for search using registration id.

**API(ukvehicledata)**

> you can use **search Criteria** using registration id

```
    http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/YOUR_API/?
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=registration_id&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]={VALUE}&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]‌​=eq
```

> method type : **GET**

**The system creates an array, as shown in the following pseudo-code.**

```
searchCriteria => [
  'filterGroups' => [
    0 => [
      'filters' => [
         0 => [
           'field' => 'registration_id',
           'value' => 'YOUR VALUE',
           'condition_type' => 'eq'
         ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: I am getting response in search controller. How can I return this response to the result page.

Comment: Call Interface and put your code in Model file.

Comment: Follow the service contact standard.

Comment: great, was my solution helped you in anyway ?

Comment: No, I have done via different way.. I have followed this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/100115/44608

and get response from block